# iOS Autolayout - constraints modifications lost on orientation change?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

If I modify my constraints (lets say activate some and deactivate others) and then rotate to a different orientation my interface snaps back to the original unmodified state. How do I preserve this changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your constraints 'properties of the class'? Or they are local variables of a function which get deallocated after you change your orientation?

The general suggestion is to keep a reference/pointer to your constraints and instead of adding/removing constraints you activate/deactivate the constraints. See [this moment of wwdc: Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/?time=984)

Comment: The constraints are in the storyboard and the corresponding view controller holds references to them. Hmm ... from what is explained in the video it looks like I would need to repeat the changes in traitCollectionDidChange. Must try it.

Comment: Yeah that's the best way of doing it. Roughly speaking see [this moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/?time=1136). (I think you've already seen it though)

Comment: However it does not work as straight forward as in the video for me. If I simply execute the changes in traitCollectionDidChange they are performed before the orientation change and are then lost. Only if I put them in DispatchQueue.main they are applied thereafter.